# Passing variable from sheet code to module code

Tags: vba, variables, excel, public

I have a problem passing variables from sheet code to module code. Here is the sheet code:

```
Public Sub Update()

Dim plan As String

plan = "PlanB"

'Code stuff here

Call LookForManualData(plan)

'Code stuff here

End Sub
```

And here is the module:

```
Public Sub LookForManualData(plan As String)

'Code stuff here

MsgBox plan

'Code stuff here

End Sub
```

Please note, that the code is simplified, and irrelevant parts are excluded. Also, that I have tried pretty much possibility for defining plan as a variable, although there has to be be something that hasn't came in my mind. The basic idea is to let the module know what plan is to be able to use it, because now it's empty.

Comment: What's you question? That code seems to work fine.

Comment: Because it doesn't pass the plan variable to the module, it is empty in LookForManualData.

Comment: There must be something happening in the code you omitted because what you posted *does* work.

Comment: I posted an answer too soon. Yes Gareth and Rory are correct. Your code does work. I missed the `ByVal` argument. So yes, can you clarify a bit more what's happening. Btw, what I posted is an alternative with the `ByVal`.

Comment: It's ByRef actually. ;) That's the default in VBA.

Comment: As others have mentioned, there must be something happening within the rest of your code which is changing `plan`. I'd suggest searching the procedure for something like `plan = "` to see if it's being changed.

Comment: @Rory In his sample yes, without being explicit.

Answer (score 1):

To pass variable values and do what you want you need to declare the variable in any module:

```
Option Explicit
Public plan As String '~~> at the very top of the module outside any sub

Public Sub Anysub()
'~~> any code
End Sub
```

Then you can then set it in any sheet code as you want and then call it in any sub.

Comment: That is not correct-you can pass arguments as in the sample posted.

Comment: @Rory, Technically this works, it's just not good practice to use globals.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting this wouldn't work. I was objecting to the statement that you *have* to use a public variable rather than passing it as an argument.

Comment: Whoa... my add-ins typically have an entire module dedicated JUST to global variables, like `MaxNumberOfFiles = 1000`, `Excel2007ForWin = 51`, `Excel2007ForWinBinary = 50`, `Blank = vbNullString` etc... is there a "best practices" discussion on using global variables somewhere that I missed?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using constants @DanWagner  and that's *ok* because constants can't be changed at runtime. Global variables can be used judiciously, but they can cause problems when you re-use the name of one at a smaller scope or another part of your program has unexpectedly changes the value of a global var on you.

Comment: I don't want my answer to attract DV. To downvoters, I explained myself in the OP's questions comment. I will edit my answer when OP clear things out. I'm not deleting prior. So at least read the whole thread before DV. I missed the `ByRef/ByVal` since I'm answering via mobile. It's until I've read @Rory comment that I noticed.

Comment: @L42 You're being down voted because this only solves the superficial problem in what many consider to be poor practice. Yes it *works*, but that doesn't make it correct. If OP clarifies and you update, I'll be happy to remove my down vote.